# CodeDom ReferencedAssemblies absolute path

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, assemblies, codedom

I'm creating a new `.exe` with a `WPF forms`. The problem is, I need to reference some assemblies.

This is how I add them:

```
var p = new CompilerParameters
{
    GenerateExecutable = true,
    TreatWarningsAsErrors = false,
    CompilerOptions = "/t:winexe",
    IncludeDebugInformation = false,
    OutputAssembly = dlg.FileName,
};


string[] assemblies = {
    "System", "System.Core", "System.Data", "mscorlib",
    "System.Drawing", "System.Windows.Forms", "Microsoft.CSharp",
    @"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase",
    @"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore",
    @"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFrameWork"
};

foreach (string a in assemblies)
{
    p.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(a + ".dll");
}
```

This is working fine, but you will notice that I have to entered the absolute path for `Windowsbase.dll`, `PresentationCore.dll` and `PresentationFrameWork.dll`, else it will throw errors because they are not found.
This will probably work not on all computers.

What could i do?

(I think I could just include the 3 `.dll`'s in the project folder and ship them with the application and reference the relative path (I can't test it now if it works), but is there a other way?)

Comment: Are you sure these assemblies are registered in the GAC? That might be the reason why they're not found otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean with GAC? Didn't changed anything in VS or in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

One way to cheat is if you reference that dll in your project, you can do the following:

```
typeof(System.Windows.Point).Assembly.Location
```

That will get you past the WindowsBase problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the problematic assemblies are registered in the [GAC (Global Assembly Cache)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as that's where your application eventually looks for them when an absolute path isn't supplied.

You can check which assemblies are registered to the GAC by browsing to `C:\Windows\Assembly` (assuming `C:\Windows` is your windows installation directory).

Comment: It look's as these .dll's are not as default in the GAC, and I will share the project with some people, so i dont want that they have to change much (such as GAC).

Comment: @Mek Those assemblies should be in the GAC for any computer that has the latest .NET Framework installed. The fact that they aren't present on your computer probably means that you don't have it installed or the installation is corrupt.

Comment: I tested it on 2 PC's and on a VM with the latest updates + .NET Framework, didn't worked.

Comment: @Mek I'm not sure if the `ReferencedAssemblies` property works like that, but have you tried passing fully qualified assembly names? For example, `PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` ?

Comment: ok, i managed to load 2 .dll's on a other way, only WindowsBase make me some problems. I looked into C:\Windows\Assembly and there is WindowsBase registered, so why isn't it working? How can i fix it?

Comment: I used: 
typeof(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher).Assembly.Location;
To get windowsbase